# laravel 8 instalation error - npm run dev throws error

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-8

I am trying to install a fresh laravel 8 project. After downloading frontend scaffolding when I try to run `npm run dev` it gives me an error. This problem also happens during installing jetstream in this `npm run dev`. I am giving error below.

```
unkno@DESKTOP-NAP4DRR MINGW64 /c/laravel projects/example
$ npm run dev

> @ dev C:\laravel projects\example
> npm run development


> @ development C:\laravel projects\example
> mix

[webpack-cli] Running multiple commands at the same time is not possible
[webpack-cli] Found commands: 'bundle', 'projects\example\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-09T03_39_54_620Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-09T03_39_54_704Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you are a Windows developer, and that you have spaces in the name of your project folder. Windows, spaces and nodejs don't like to behave very nicely together.

Try removing the spaces from name of your project path and see if this addresses the issue for you.

**Update**: As per a similar question, [Laravel, error when running npm run dev on fresh new installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639184/laravel-error-when-running-npm-run-dev-on-fresh-new-installation), this solved the users issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and I don't have any empty spaces on my project path

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem a few weeks ago. What I figured out was that on windows that instead of running the command **npm install && npm run dev** it needed to be **npm install and npm run-dev**.

Also make sure you have the latest node and npm versions install. Perform a npm audit fix as well to fix any vulnerabilities.

Comment: P.S I forgot to add if you are using windows don't use and use -and. Powershell does not recognize it. Happy Coding !

Comment: Welcome to SO! FYI: you can edit your answer at any time by using the [edit] link below your answer, e.g. to add additional information or fix mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

### Try doing a full reset:

```
rm -rf node_modules

rm package-lock.json yarn.lock

npm cache clear --force

npm install
```

It works for me, on Laravel 9

Thanks to Sir [Jeffrey Way](https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/1072#issuecomment-319401164)