# Laravel, error when running npm run dev on fresh new installation

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I've just created a new laravel 8 project, but I have an issue when running npm install and npm run dev, more specifically when running npm run dev. I've never had this issue before, and hadn't made any changes to my NodeJs or something like that. I was able to compile my dependencies without any error, but today I encountered this error.

Here's the output.

```
Admin@DESKTOP-KH5JMQG MINGW64 /c/Proyectos Web/Dashboarding
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\@types\browser-sync\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1203 packages from 531 contributors and audited 1207 packages in 102.075s

94 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

And then

```
$ npm run dev

> @ dev C:\Proyectos Web\Dashboarding
> npm run development


> @ development C:\Proyectos Web\Dashboarding
> mix

[webpack-cli] Running multiple commands at the same time is not possible
[webpack-cli] Found commands: 'bundle', 'Web\Dashboarding\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-09T03_45_41_921Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-09T03_45_41_975Z-debug.log
```

This is the log file content:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.9
3 info using node@v14.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Proyectos Web\Dashboarding\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Admin\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Admin\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SPSS\DataCollection\6\Accessories;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\IBM\SPSS\DataCollection\6\DMOM;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3;C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: C:\Proyectos Web\Dashboarding
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Proyectos Web\Dashboarding
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.9
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try having your project in a directory that does not include spaces, and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my answer on [laravel 8 instalation error - npm run dev throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639133/laravel-8-instalation-error-npm-run-dev-throws-error), you are a Windows developer and have spaces in the name of your project path.

Try removing the spaces and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks, This worked, it's kinda weird because i have several projects on the same folder and never had this behavior, but it's ok for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not a problem, I've been caught by it before. Please mark as the correct answer.